# Can jQuery select a string that matches a regex?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am writing an HTTP request tutorial for beginners.  I have code that looks like:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://xxx.com/yy/zzz?a=1&b=2', auth=('1234', '5678'))
r.text
```

I would like to use jQuery to dynamically select the `?a=1&b=2~ snippet of code and highlight it (because those values are dynamic and depend on what the user types in).

Is there a way to do a jQuery select that matches a regex?

Unfortunately I can not wrap that area in a special span to select it that way.

Thanks!

Comment: highlighting in html is usually done by wrapping the highlighted area with html tags... If you can't wrap them due to whatever reason, I think this would be very difficult, if not impossible

Comment: You can't even wrap it in a span using jQuery?

Comment: If I could select it in jquery, I could do whatever I wanted (including adding a span!).  But not otherwise.

Comment: There's a great language for doing things like this. It's called HTML.

Comment: Very funny, but trust me that it's not an option.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the element that contains the code sample, which I assume you've put in a `<pre>` or `<code>` block.  Then you can just grab all of the html contents of it, and use a regular string replace to add in any additional HTML elements you might need.

Here is [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jonypawks/6zWdz/) which has the code you provided in a `<pre>` tag and adds a span around the query string.